# Mcar error with lists

Tags: scheme, racket

My code so far:

```
(define (longest-common-prefix lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((equal? lst1 lst2) lst1)
        (else
         (longest-common-prefix ls1 (car lst2)))))
```

I need it to return the longest common prefix of 2 lists. For example, applied to `'(1 2 3)` and `'(1 2)`, it should return `'(1 2)`. Every time I run this, it keeps saying `mcar: contract violation`.

Comment: Are you sure that your code contains `car`, and not for instance `mcar`? While that's not your problem (your solution is also not correct), it does explain your error message.

Comment: No my code does not contain mcar. how would I be able to fix my code?

Comment: You need to post a small but complete program that illustrates the error. Make sure to mention what language level you're using.

Comment: Using one of the report schemes would use m-versions of all the pair related procedures and thus this error would be more about wrong contract than what type of pair is used. How can you be sure `lst2` is a pair?` at the point you are doing `(car lst2)`? How can you compare if two elements in a list is the same with comparing the two whole lists?